# Como fazer em um select html, ao clicar selecionar mais de uma linha de uma vez?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, query, option

Eu tenho uma query que me traz as 3 primeiras letras do nome de um mês com os últimos dois dígitos do ano por exemplo: JAN.16 no meu combobox ele me traz os meses independente por exemplo: JAN.16 FEV.16... e por ai vai.

Eu queria que o combobox ou clicar em JAN.16 pegue também FEV.16 e MAR.16, em 3 em 3 meses ou fazer um bloco desses 3 meses no combobox esse valor do combobox, eu pego do banco de dados com a query abaixo

```
select mes from tabela where mes in ('JAN.16');
select mes from tabela where mes in ('FEV.16');... e por ai vai chegar DEZ.16.
```

Tentei assim, também não foi réplica a informação:

```
select mes from tabela where (mes like 'JAN.%' or mes like 'FEV.%' or mes like 'MAR.%');
```

pegar esses 3 meses só que no combobox aparecesse apenas uma informação alguém sabe se tem como fazer isso?

```
$q1 = mysql_query("select distinct mes from reparo.falhas_consolidadas where mes like 'JAN%' or mes like 'FEV%' or mes like 'MAR%'");

<td><select multiple name="month[]" id="month">
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
            <?php 
                    while($m1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1)){
                        echo "<option value='$m1[0]'>Q1</option>";
                    }
            ?>      
</select>
```

O que replica é o `option`, mas é por causa do `while`, o que eu gostaria é de um `option` para pegar o valor dos meses, esse valor está em linhas diferentes.

Comment: Poderia postar mais informações? O que replica? O que não funciona? Em que lugar o combobox entra?

Comment: Não seria só por os 3 no option? `<option>Jan Fev Mar</option>`

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi exatamente a parte da seleção como deve funcionar, explica melhor que edito minha resposta se necessário.

Mas em relação a busca no banco é só fazer o seguinte:

```
select mes from tabela where mes in ('JAN.16', 'FEV.16', 'MAR.16');
```

Tu pode tanto mandar os 3 valores separados para o PHP como mandar uma string e dar um explode no PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Bem pelo que entendi queres pegar em um mes e pegar os 2 meses seguintes ? 
Bem podes começar então por ver o value que estas a atribuir a tua option.

Vamos supor que tens 3 options

```
<option value = 1 >JAN.16</option>
<option value = 2 >FEV.16</option>
<option value = 3 >MAR.16</option>
```

Podes enviar através de um formulario por post ou Get o teu value ou seja 1 , 2 ou 3 neste caso.
E envias outro valor que vai ser o teu value+2 para sabermos onde acaba.

Recebes isso no teu ficheiro php onde estás a fazer o sql e vais dar select por mesId 
$i= $valueoriginal;
 ou seja o que clicas te e envias te pelo formulario

```
select mes from tabela where mesid in ( for($i;$i<=$valorqueagentesomou;$i++) {

if ($i<$valorqueagentesomou)
{
'.$i.";".'
}
else {
.'$i'.
}

}

);
```

Answer (score 1):

Por favor, veja se o que você quer resolve assim:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `mes` SEPARATOR ', ' ) `mes`
FROM   `tabela`
WHERE  `mes` IN('JAN.16', 'FEV.16', 'MAR.16');
```